# Something wrong with delete records

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-delete, records

I'm trying to solve problem with delete records from mysql, please see the code

```
<?php 
 $dbcs = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database-name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbcs))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$product_list = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($dbcs,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

              $product_id = $row["product_id"];
              $product_name = $row["product_name"];
              $product_category = $row["product_category"];
              $product_retail_price = $row["product_retail_price"];
              $product_price = $row["product_price"];
              $product_detail = $row["product_detail"];
              $product_image = $row["screenshot"];
              $screenshot = $row["screenshot"];

              $product_list .= '<table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td width="172" valign="top"> echo <img src="' . GW_UPLOADPATH . $screenshot .'" width="111" height="149" alt="<?php echo           $product_name; ?>" /><br /><a href="../product_images/<?php echo $product_id; ?>.jpg">View Full Size Image</a></td>
    <td width="85" class="product-text">' . $product_id . '</td>
    <td width="402" class="product-text">' . $product_name . '</td>
    <td width="108" align="center" class="product-text">' . $product_price . '</td>
    <td width="34" align="center" class="product-text"><a href="edit_product.php?pid=' . $product_id . '">Edit</a></td>
    <td width="56" align="center" class="product-text"><a  href="product.php?deleteid=' . $product_id . '">Delete </a></td>
    <td width="56" align="center" class="product-text"><a href="view_product.php?pid=' . $product_id . '">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table> ';

    }

    if (empty($product_list)) {
    $product_list = "You have no product listed in your data yet";
}
mysqli_close($dbcs);       

?>
```

and then this is for php delete code

```
<?php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '? <a href="product.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="product.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// remove item from system and delete its picture
// delete from database
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
    $sql ("DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// unlink the image from server
// Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $pictodelete = ("../product_images/$id_to_delete.jpg");
    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
                unlink($pictodelete);
    }
    header("location: product.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

When I run that to select item and delete by press delete and press yes, i got error said

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC() in C:\VertrigoServ\www\shopone\admin\data\product.php on line 131
```

what his mean by that and how can is solve that!
AM

Comment: Replace `$sql ("DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());` with 
`mysqli_query($sql,"DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
  $sql ("DELETE FROM ...
      ^---missing =
```

And you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do **NOT** use this code until you've learned about the problem and how to avoid it.

Comment: uh, yes it does. `[space](...)` is treated as a function call with a blank function name, which is a PHP syntax errors. Functions must have non-empty names.

Comment: I changed that by adding this $sql=mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC"); but i'm still getting errors said mysql_query() [&lt;a href='function.mysql-query'&gt;function.mysql-query&lt;/a&gt;]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\VertrigoServ\www\shopone\admin\data\product.php on line on line 74 which is same line where i add... what this mean by that and how to solve that!

Comment: You're calling `mysql_query` instead of `mysqli_query()` (note the **i**) in there. The two libraries are NOT compatible and can NOT be used interchangeably.

Comment: No syntax error occur when I run this code:

`function sayboo() { /* Do something */ }

$func_name = "sayboo";
$func_name        ();`

Comment: put an argument in the `()`. `$func_name ('foo')` will blow up

Comment: i have changed that too mysqli_query() but then i'm getting new errors that new to me which it said Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\VertrigoServ\www\shopone\admin\data\product.php on line 74 ... which is same line i change to mysqli_query... this is new to me and what is this mean !

Comment: thanks so much i have fixed that line by put this if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC"))  but it does not do delete things, does this code is correct to product $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
$sql= ("DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: yes i have solved that i forgot to change to if statements. you guys thanks for help.

Comment: @andy Did you look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19455121/1415724) in regards to deleting?

Answer (score 0):

First, you're saving a string into variable `$sql`...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY product_id DESC";
```

...then you call a function with the name denoted in variable `$sql`.

```
$sql ("DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1")
```

You are using a variable as a function. I guess you want to use the function `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: It's obvious that the OP is missing a line of code to execute the delete function. This would be what should be done `mysqli_query($sql,"DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());`

Answer (score -1):

You are using `$sql` like function, so PHP is trying to execute function with name from it.

You have to require your query using `mysql_query()`.

Also consider moving to `PDO`, which is better than deprecated `mysql_*` (`prepared statements` are worth learning also).

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** This was too long for a comment at the time and I've added a few other details today.

- `mysql_error()` does not mix with the mysqli_ api. It needs to read as `mysqli_error($dbcs)`.

---

I created a table on my own webserver using your source code, and concluded the following to work.

But first, if your delete file/function is in a seperate file, then you will need your DB connection credentials inside that file, otherwise it won't work, unless you have it as an include or a global setting.

In your case, it would resemble:

```
$dbcs = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database-name");

mysqli_query($dbcs,"DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($dbcs));
```

Replace:

```
$sql ("DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($dbcs));
```

with:

```
mysqli_query($sql,"DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($dbcs));
```

or in your case, it could be:

```
mysqli_query($dbcs,"DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($dbcs));
```

However, this is open to SQL injection. It is best to use a prepared statement for this.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Yet, if `$id_to_delete` is always to be an integer, you can use `(int)` for it.

I.e.:

```
$id_to_delete = (int)$_GET['yesdelete'];
```